# White screen in the pgadmin program

Tags: pgadmin

The pgadmin 4 version 6 program does not start for me. It does not give any errors, only a white screen and the "Object" tab. What is the problem? (pgadmin runs as a desktop application)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GFc2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is committed to the pgAdmin repo. There's a new release this week(v6.2) which will include the fix.